# How can I create 1 ID for a group of customers in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have a list of customers who have different contracts with my service company.

- Sometimes we can have different customers per contracts. *Example:
  Karen and her boyfriend Will have a contract.*
- Sometimes a group of customers can have different contracts. *Example: Karen and Will have multiple contracts with me.*

Here is the table:

```
idCustomer  idContract          NameCust
-----------------------------------------
1           A                   Karen
1           B                   Will
2           A                   Karen
2           B                   Will
3           C                   Steph
4           C                   Peter
```

But because Karen and Will can have multiple contracts, I want a unique id for them and other group of customers. Result table I want:

```
idCustomer  idContract  NameCust    Customer_GroupID
-----------------------------------------------------
1           A           Karen       1
1           B           Will        1
2           A           Karen       1
2           B           Will        1
3           C           Steph       2
4           C           Peter       2
```

I'm stuck because I tried different things that doesn't give me the result I need. I find in the forum someone who used Dense_Rank function but here is the result:

```
SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY idCustomers) AS Customer_GroupID,
    IdCustomers,
    IdContract
FROM 
    Table
```

Here is the result:

```
Cust_GroupID  idCustomer    idContract
--------------------------------------
1              1             A
2              1             B
1              2             A
2              2             B
3              3             C
3              4             C
```

I even tried to use multiple select, not exists but nothing.

Comment: It's not clear how Karen and Will have different `idCustomer` (in your first table)? You assign different IDs to same customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that I have understood your requirement. Still you should throw little more sample data to make it absolute clear to all. Append few more varied sample data in existing one.

You should test with different sample data and let me know if its not working.

Sample Data,

```
create table #test(idCustomer int,idContract varchar(50) , NameCust varchar(50))
insert into #test  (idCustomer ,idContract , NameCust ) VALUES
 (1,'A','Karen')
,(1,'B','Will' )
,(2,'A','Karen')
,(2,'B','Will' )
,(3,'C','Steph')
,(4,'C','Peter')
```

## Method 1- SET BASED Approach,

```
;with CTE as
(
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by idCustomer)rn
from #test
)
,CTE1 as
(
select t.id,t.idContract,t.NameCust
, isnull(t1.idCustomer,t.idCustomer)customerGroupID 
from CTE t
outer apply(
select top 1 idCustomer 
from CTE t1 
where t1.id< t.id 
and((t.idCustomer=t1.idCustomer) 
or (t.idContract=t1.idContract)) 
order by t1.id 
)t1
)
,CTE2 AS(
select * 
,DENSE_RANK()OVER( order by customerGroupID )Customer_GroupID
from CTE1
)

select * from CTE2
```

## Method 2- RBAR (using cursor),

```
create table #test1(id int identity(1,1),idCustomer int
,idContract varchar(50) , NameCust varchar(50),customer_Groupid int)

insert into #test1  (idCustomer ,idContract 
, NameCust,customer_Groupid ) 
select idCustomer ,idContract , NameCust,null 
from #test

DECLARE @idCustomer INT
DECLARE @idContract varchar(50)
DECLARE @id INT
declare @customer_Groupid int
DECLARE @getCustomer CURSOR
SET @getCustomer = CURSOR FOR
SELECT id, idCustomer,idContract
FROM #test1
OPEN @getCustomer
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getCustomer INTO @id, @idCustomer,@idContract
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

select top 1 @customer_Groupid=customer_Groupid 
from #test1 where id<@id order by id desc

if  not exists(select 1 from #test1 where id<@id 
and (idCustomer=@idCustomer or idContract=@idContract))
BEGIN

select top 1 @customer_Groupid=customer_Groupid 
from #test1 where id<@id order by id desc
if(@customer_Groupid is not null)
set @customer_Groupid=@customer_Groupid+1

end


if(@customer_Groupid is null)
set @customer_Groupid=1

update #test1 set customer_Groupid=@customer_Groupid where id=@id

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getCustomer INTO @id, @idCustomer,@idContract
END
CLOSE @getCustomer
DEALLOCATE @getCustomer


select * from #test1

drop table #test1
drop table #test
```

Comment: Thank you so much @KumarHarsh both worked perffectly but i used the first method.

Comment: @It'smeAndYou,yes Set Based approach should be always preferred.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a need to create an interim table of NameCustGroup like

```
NameCustList  idCustomer idContract
Karen,Will    1          A,B
Karen,Will    2          A,B
Peter,Steph   3          C
Peter,Steph   4          C
```

And then use that to create

```
Customer_GroupID  idCustomer  idContract
1                 1           A,B
1                 2           A,B
2                 3           C
2                 4           D
```

The interim table seems hardest, because the NameCustList needs to be formed either by Common idCustomer or Common idContract. This is a work in progress... ...